# Common Lisp: Does `load` do `compile-file` things?

Tags: compilation, load, common-lisp

Suppose I have a file named "includes.cl", inside which there are several function definitions. Now I have two ways to use these functions:

1. `(load "includes.cl")`
2. `(load (compile-file "includes.cl"))`

Is the latter faster than the former? I only concern the runtime speed of function invoking.

Comment: what does the Lisp spec or the implementation manuals say? LOAD is not COMPILE-FILE and does not call COMPILE-FILE.

Comment: @RainerJoswig So the former is slower than the latter during runtime execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the question you ask, there is no way to say a priori which of your two forms is faster. However, your second form will probably result in the functions and macros found in "includes.cl" being executed faster.

More to the point though, just like you would not recompile a `C` library every time you link something against it, you should not [recompile](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cmp_fi.htm) a `Lisp` library before every [`load`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_load.htm).

At the very least you should be using something like [`load-compile-maybe`](http://clocc.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/clocc/clocc/file/tip/src/cllib/fileio.lisp#l393) or a Lisp analogue of [make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29), such as [asdf](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/).

EDIT: you are using SBCL which does not have an interpreter, only a compiler. This means that all code is compiled before is it executed, so the two forms in your question are equivalent. However, the bulk of the cost is in `compile-file`, not in `load`, so it is a very good idea to compile the file *once* and then load it using `(load "includes")` (note the lack of file type, AKA, extension).

Comment: I have tried some experiments, and the results show that the execution times are the same for `(load "includes.cl")` and `(load (compile-file "includes.cl"))`. Why? I use SBCL.

Comment: Because the compiled version is already processed thus loads faster, but that win is eaten by `compile-file`. Basically, _in SBCL_, `load` of a source is the same as `load`+`compile-file`.